# Fail to install Mircosoft SEAL

Tags: installation, seal

When i used vcpkg to install SEAL, it occurs this:

```
Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `.\vcpkg update`, then
submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:
  Package: seal:x86-windows
  Vcpkg version: 2021-01-13-unknownhash

Additionally, attach any relevant sections from the log files above.
```

**C:\src\vcpkg\vcpkg\buildtrees\seal\config-x86-windows-dbg-out.log**

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29335.0
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29335.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x86/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x86/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Build type (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE): Debug
-- Microsoft SEAL debug mode: ON
-- Microsoft GSL: found
-- Found ZLIB: optimized;C:/src/vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib/zlib.lib;debug;C:/src/vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/debug/lib/zlibd.lib (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.11") 
-- ZLIB: found
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/src/vcpkg/vcpkg/buildtrees/seal/x86-windows-dbg/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

**C:\src\vcpkg\vcpkg\buildtrees\seal\config-x86-windows-dbg-err.log**

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:186 (message):
  Zstandard: must be static
```

`what's the maining of "Zstandard: must be static" ???`

Please tell me how to fix it or how to install SEAL on Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEAL requires Zstandard to be built statically. You can only use vcpkg to install a static SEAL if you want to have Zstandard support. To do this, specify the triple as follows (for example): `.\vcpkg install seal:windows-x64-static`.

Comment: i have installed the SEAL by Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 .Thanks